# make functions dependant on one another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jquery and am trying to make some function to fire after each other. DOes the following seems right. I'm pretty much calling a function in a function.

```js
  $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            var obj;
            var items = new Array();


            $j(document).ready(function() {
                                
                function setTopicsSpans() {               
                    // do stuff
                    //.....
                }
                
                function ajaxGetTopicRatings() {
                    var request = $j.ajax({
                        url: "json.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: {"items": items},
                        cache: true,
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    });                    
                    request.done(function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        setTopicsSpans();
                    });
                    //......
                }
                function setTopicsArray() {
                    $j('[data-tid]').each(function() {
                        items.push(this.getAttribute('data-tid'));
                    });
                    ajaxGetTopicRatings();
                }
                
                setTopicsArray();
                
            });
```

Now I read a bit about callback functions. but when I put in put in for example "setTopicsSpans" in function ajaxGetTopicRatings(setTopicSpans) I get an an error that the function: "setTopicsSpans" doesnt exist. Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxvdjsom/)

Comment: I suspect spelling errors due to the confusing name `setTopic*s*Span*s*`. Make sure you are always using the correct number of S's (3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I totally misread the question on my first go. Here goes, callbacks:

You're already using a sort of callback through the "request.done" method. If you want to run a function like you propose, you could do something like this:

```
function ajaxGetTopicRatings(myCallback) {
    //code code code

    if (myCallback && typeof(myCallback) === "function") {
        myCallback();
    }
}
```

then you can call by...

```
ajaxGetTopicRatings(function () { setTopicsSpans() });
```

This will ensure that "setTopicsSpans" is not run until it's called within "ajaxGetTopicRatings".

(Make sure you enter the function name correctly, as opposed to the original question: *"...but when I put in put in for example "setTopicsSpans" in function ajaxGetTopicRatings(setTopicSpans) I get an an err.."*)

Adding a callback like this, in the end of a function, is still no guarantee that it will be the last thing to run. In your example, the last thing to run will most likely be "request.done()", since the code won't wait for this. That's probably a good place for the callback to reside.

I added a small example of function calling order in the below snippet.

```js
function test1CB1(myCallback) {
  document.write('test1 CB1 hit<br/>');
  myCallback();
}

function test1CB2(myCallback) {
  document.write('test1 CB2 hit<br/>');
  myCallback();
}

function test1CB3() {
  document.write('test1 CB3 hit<br/><br/>');
  test2();
}

function test2CB1() {
  document.write('test2 CB1 hit<br/>');
}

function test2CB2() {
  document.write('test2 CB2 hit<br/>');
}

function test2CB3() {
  document.write('test2 CB3 hit<br/>');
}

function test2() {
  document.write('Standard behaviour - inner most function gets called first<br/>');
  test2CB1(test2CB2(test2CB3()));
}

document.write('Functions fire after each other using callbacks<br/>');
test1CB1(function() {
  test1CB2(function() {
    test1CB3();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll test your snippet out. Appreciate it!

Comment: It's the first parameter in each function. The reason for wrapping the call in a anon. function, is so that it will not be executed first (as calling it without this would mean). You could achive the same thing by adding a function WITHIN the ajaxGetTopicRating, and then calling this though the parameter (without using the anon. function). I hope that makes sense. You can read more about it here: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/

Comment: I see you edited your comment, but I'll leave my comment in anyway (even though it doesnt make sense anymore, heh)

Comment: thank you, I was thinking and typing at the same time :) Appreciate the follow up

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your example should work fine under normal circumstances (i.e. there will be no unresolved references).

But I suggest that you use `$.getJSON()` instead, or set `dataType: 'json'` in the options object argument of the `$.ajax()` instead of `contentType` as you probably have mistaken one for the other here.